# get_post_meta don't work in my wp template

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php $promo_icon = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'promo_icon', true);?>
        <?php
        global $post;
        $args=array( 'posts_per_page'=> 4, 'post_type'=>'promo');
        $myposts=get_posts($args);
        foreach($myposts as $post): setup_postdata($post);?>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                <span class="ca-icon">
                <?php echo $promo_icon; ?>
                </span>
                <div class="ca-content">
                    <h2 class="ca-main"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <h3 class="ca-sub"><?php the_content(); ?></h3>
                </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

At first i register custom post in my functions.php file. which name promo...then i used the code in the index.php and used the value in custom field....but the_title and the_content is working and get_post_meta not working..

Comment: `$post` must exist ... you have to use `get_post_meta()` inside the loop (or get the post ID by some other means)

Comment: You are calling `get_post_meta($post->ID [...])` before setting up `global $post;`.

Comment: thanks.. now work@ GeraldSchneider and mathielo